# What will be the remainder in the following case?

Tags: number-theory

Exp.

$10^{10} + 10^{100}+10^{1000} + 10^{10000}+--------+ 10^{10000000000}\div 7=?$

I don't have knowledge to solve this.
help.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can reduce $10^a\bmod 7$ to $3^a\bmod 7$. Notice that the period of $3^a\bmod 7$ is $6$ since $3$ is a primitive of modular $7$. Thus compute $a\bmod 6$, and adding the equation up should be easy.

I think it is possible to derive a general formula for this kind of problem using Euler function etc..

$a\bmod b$ means the remainder of $a$ dividing by $b$ here.